# ng2-auto-complete having overlay placeholder issue

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I am using ng2-auto-complete to get a searchable drop down with Angular2 (version 2.3.1) and Angular Material (version 2.0.0-beta.1).

I am facing issue with placeholder overlay with the selected value.
When I select any value from drop-down without typing a search string, the selected value gets overlayed with the html placeholder of that input field.

It works fine when we search a string into dropdown and then select it.

Below is my code sample :

```
<input md-input ng2-auto-complete
           [formControl]="company"
           [source]="clients"
           [list-formatter]="companyFormatter"
           align="end"
           value-property-name="shortname"
           display-property-name="shortname"
           no-match-found-text="No Match Found"
           placeholder="Client Name"
           (valueChanged)="someFunction(company)"
           class="form-control"
           tabindex="1">
```

Where,

```
clients = ["{shortname:abc},{shortname:efg},{shortname:hij}"]
```

Any[See Image Here. The view looks like this and thats not good for user.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPWKv.png)

Comment: update the equivalent component code as well

Comment: @Aravind : how can I update the component code? Its just an external package I have added using `npm install ng2-auto-complete` this command.